# Getting biggest interval of rows with same value

Tags: mysql, sql, business-intelligence

I have a table with three columns (lending_id int, installment_n int, status text) and I wonder how to retrieve the value (int) of the biggest gap of  NOK (status) per lending_id.

For the following example:

```
 lending_id, installment_n, status
      32882,             1,     OK
      32882,             2,     OK
      32882,             3,     OK
      32882,             4,     OK
      32882,             5,     OK
      32882,             6,     OK
      32882,             7,     OK
      32882,             8,     NOK
      32882,             9,     OK
      32882,             10,    OK
      32882,             11,    NOK
      32882,             12,    NOK
      32882,             13,    NOK
      32882,             14,    OK
      32882,             15,    OK
      32882,             16,    NOK
      32882,             17,    NOK
      32882,             18,    NOK
      32882,             19,    NOK
      32882,             20,    NOK
      32882,             21,    NOK
      32882,             22,    NOK
      32882,             23,    OK
      32882,             24,    NOK
       1005,              1,    OK
       1005,              2,    NOK
       1005,              3,    NOK
       1005,              4,    NOK
       1005,              5,    OK
```

The result would be:

```
Lending_id = 32882 is 6 (from 16 to 22) 
and Lendind_id = 1005 is 2 (from 2 to 4)
```

It's very close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124330/sum-highest-consecutive-occurrence) but when I get NOK status at the bottom it does broke the result set.

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum highest consecutive occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124330/sum-highest-consecutive-occurrence)

Comment: @Binarus This is not the same question

Comment: @Binarus The other question don handle last row with different value.

Comment: I think it is the same question. You even have added a comment in the other post regarding that problem.

Comment: @Binarus The simple fact of last value being different broke it all.

Comment: Using first solution on previous question I can't reproduce the issue with NOK at the bottom see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bca848/1 and  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/308342/1 `also your results seem wrong`  e.g. 16 to 22 is 7

Comment: @JulinhodaAdelaide Yes, I have got that. But you already have mentioned / asked for a solution to that problem in your other post, so your other post plus your comments at your other post are the same as this post.